# Store console output in a file - Python , unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unit-testing, output

I have a python script in which I wrote some unit tests and I am using selenium.

I want to extract the whole output of the console (not only my prints but also the unit test related results), so that I can import them later in my test management tool.

[image: Output]

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import requests
import sys


class TestUbuntuHomepage(unittest.TestCase):
    global strs

    strs = []

    def setUp(self):
        sys.stdout = open("C:\\Users\\Marialena\\Downloads\\out2.log", 'wt')

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Marialena\\Downloads\\selenium-drivers\\geckodriver")


    def testTitle(self):
        self.driver.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')

        if self.assertIn('Ubuntu', self.driver.title):
            strs.append('test'})


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Using `sys.stdout = open("C:\\Users\\Marialena\\Downloads\\out2.log", 'wt')` I get in the file everything I have printed and I also get this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.3.3\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in 
>       main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not
>   JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)   File
>   "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\main.py",
>   line 95, in **init**
>       self.runTests()   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\main.py",
>   line 256, in runTests
>       self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.3.3\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\unittestpy.py", line 304, in run
>       return super(TeamcityTestRunner, self).run(test)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\runner.py",
>   line 176, in run
>       test(result)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 84, in **call**
>       return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 122, in run
>       test(result)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 84, in **call**
>       return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 122, in run
>       test(result)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 84, in **call**
>       return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py",
>   line 122, in run
>       test(result)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 653, in **call**
>       return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\Marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 624, in run
>       result.stopTest(self)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2017.3.3\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\unittestpy.py", line 260, in stopTest
>       output = sys.stdout.getvalue() AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

Any help with this, please? Thank you.

Comment: It may be a bug with PyCharm itself: [link here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000019990-Unittest-Error-AttributeError-file-object-has-no-attribute-getvalue-).

Comment: I would try restoring the original `sys.stdout` in `tearDown`...

Comment: @ely I'll have a look if this is a pycharm issue. thank you

Comment: @zvone I get the same error also in tearDown but thanks

Comment: @Marialena If you are having "the same error" even after doing `self.original_stdout = sys.stdout` in setUp and then `sys.stdout = self.original_stdout` in tearDown, you should probably move the whole stdout handling into each test. It seems that PyCharm already replacing stdout with something it expects to be there after each test is run.

Comment: @zvone If I move the replacing of the stdout at the tearDown I get the error that the file is not closed, nothing else.  Is there a way I could get in my file the whole output and not only what I print though? (please see the screenshot in my post)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *PyCharm* is replacing sys.stdout with its own stream, so when you replace it with a file stream, *PyCharm* fails to use it.

So, limit your interventions to the scope of one function, to avoid interference with *PyCharm*.

This is the general idea:

```
def testTitle(self):
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open("C:\\Users\\Marialena\\Downloads\\out2.log", 'wt')

    # your test code goes here

    sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Now, from the outside, it will look like `sys.stdout` was never modified.

Of course, you'll want to improve on some things:

- handle exceptions in test - restore `stdout` in a `finally` block
- avoid deleting the file in each test - open the file in *append* mode
- avoid having to copy-and-paste this code in each test - make a context manager

```py
@contextmanager
def redirected_stdout(filename):
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(filename, 'at')
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

and then:

```
def testTitle(self):
    with redirected_stdout("C:\\Users\\Marialena\\Downloads\\out2.log"):
        # your test code goes here
```

**Alternatively:**

Investigate how *PyCharm* expects `sys.stdout` to behave and make your own class which does both: writes to file *and* provides the API which *PyCharm* expects.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution, suggestion and your time. However I tried to specify my search to unit test results so i am executing my test using this command: `pytest --junitxml junit-results.xml sel-test.py` and I am now able to get the output and any errors occurred with this. Not the best solution as I couldn't use it directly from my script but it still works.